# Combining legends where each individual legend contains only a subset of items on the common legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, legend

I have a series of 16 plots which plot the same two continuous variables. Each individual plot shows only a subset of the entire dataset and I want to colour all the plots with the same colour scale, which shows a third independent, discrete variable. There are 9 values of this variable in total but each plot only contains a subset of these values. So if I use ggarrange and common legend it just plots the legend of the first sub-plot rather than plotting the common legend which encompasses all the different sub-plots. What's the best way to fix this?

```
library(ggplot2)

N_B_samples <- ggarrange(
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="San1"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="San1"),
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="San2"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="San2"),
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="122"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="122"),
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="DC46A"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="DC46A"),
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="DC46B"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="DC46B"),
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="DC48B"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="DC48B"),
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="DR10"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="DR10"),
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="X1008"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="X1008"),
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="X1348"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="X1348"),
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="DR9"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="DR9"),
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="HA1"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="HA1"),
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="HA2"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="HA2"),
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="VI1808"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="VI1808"),
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="275"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="275"),
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="C13"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="C13"),
  ggplot(subset(results,mount=="ZS15"),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + th + labs(title="ZS15"),
  common.legend = TRUE, legend = "right"
)
```

This is what happens without common.legend (showing the individual legends).

[image]

And this is what happens with common.legend = TRUE.

[image]

I want the colour for each mineral to be consistent across each plot and to only show one legend which covers all minerals.

Comment: is "Mineral" a factor?  If not, can you try setting it as one?

Comment: You could probably achieve your desired result more easily using facetting, i.e. something like `ggplot(result),aes(B,N,colour=Mineral)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~Mount) + th`.